# How to update table in prestashop1.6

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to update a table in prestashop 1.6. The table I'm trying to update is `ps_employee`, but when I try to do the following I get an error.

```
$where='email='.$this->email_customer;
$pwd=******;
$updateEmployee= Db::getInstance()->update(
    'employee', 
    array('passwd' => $pwd),
    $where
);
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to the error at this time. However, this code works when trying to update where `id_employee=6`, but when I try to use it with an email adress it fails.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVy7K.png)

Comment: Sorry i can't open my error code but i know when i try to update using where 'id_employee=6' it work but when i using where 'email=email' i can't update it

Comment: You probably need to escape the `$this->email_customer`, otherwise the query will end up like `WHERE email = foo@bar.com` which causes a syntax error.

Comment: Hi you can click link to screenshot on "enter image description here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this line as below to avoid syntax error:-

```
    $where="email='$this->email_customer'";
```

**Note**:- Always encrypt your password before saving it to DB. One of the simplest technique is MD5. eg. `$password = md5($_POST['password']);`

Comment: password is okay but i to update password where email=email

Comment: if i update using where id_employee=number is working but when i use email=email is not working i don't know why..!

Comment: when i use your  $where="email='$this->email_customer'"; it update all rows of my ps_employee

Comment: okay thanks you all gay! now is working when i use this " $updateEmployee=Db::getInstance()->update('employee', $data, "email='$thisemail'"); "